# Running automation test with Grunt task

Tags: java, node.js, selenium-webdriver, automation, gruntjs

I have a test automation project using Selenium Webdriver in java. I want to use Grunt task (I am new to Grunt) to start drive the test. I use grunt-selenium-webdriver plugin (Git here: https://github.com/levexis/grunt-selenium-webdriver)

I installed the this plugin and added this section **webdriver** in the Gruntfile.js

```
grunt.initConfig({
    webdriver: {
        options: {
            desiredCapabilities: {
                browserName: 'chrome'
            }
        },
        login: {
            tests: ['Test/Automation/NextGenWebViewerUI/src/test/java/com/autodesk/infraworks/webviewer/tests/*.java'],
        },

    },
});

grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-selenium-webdriver');
```

Then, I run this task with this command

```
grunt webdriver
```

But I got the warning:

```
>> Grunt script called with:
>> Tasks: webdriver
>> Options:
Warning: Task "webdriver" not found. Use --force to continue.
```

Can anyone help me out or have usage examples?. Much appreciated!

Comment: You are missing some configuration. Take a look at the example - http://gruntjs.com/sample-gruntfile.

Comment: @AleksandrM: thanks, I took at the example, all of the plugins for javaScript, I use Java, so it seemed not working this way. I updated my question. Any thought?

Comment: Java? Why do you use grunt then? According to documentation of `grunt-selenium-webdriver` there are 3 tasks in it (selenium_start, selenium_stop and selenium_phantom_hub).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem with grunt-shell, execute maven command in a grunt-shell.